# how to achieve this this horizontal line from css or bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in a project which involves html,css and bootstrap for front end designing.

Is there any way to get this view either from bootstrap itself or using core css?
can someone provide me a code how to get this line
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution using `pseudo` element.  This solution will adjust to the width of the page when resized.

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 2px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 1px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
li:last-child {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm this could be done in 100 ways and this is probably not the cleanest one, but it works :) 
Im creating a `div.line` with 3 `div.bullets` where the last bullet has a before AND an after assigned to it.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22226/)